# R regex match mentioning by @nickname, stringr or grep

Tags: regex, r

I cannot get this `regex` working in `R`. I have a string which consists of many nicknames prefixed by `@` char, and I would like to get a list of all of them.

My regex `@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` matches only first occurrence.

None of this code works:

```
library(stringr)    
str_extract("nowy commit, nowa przygoda @oski @data2 @pankote testujemy kod @oski2", '@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+')
[1] "@oski"

grep(pattern = '@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+', x = "nowy commit, nowa przygoda @oski @data2 @pankote testujemy kod @oski2", value = T)
[1] "nowy commit, nowa przygoda @oski @data2 @pankote testujemy kod @oski2"
```

I would like to get result:

```
[1] "@oski"
[2] "@data2"
[3] "@pankote"
[4] "@oski2"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `str_extract_all("nowy commit, nowa przygoda @oski @data2 @pankote testujemy kod @oski2", '@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+')[[1]]`

Comment: Base R version `regmatches(txt,gregexpr("@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+",txt))` - `grep` doesn't return substrings, it only returns which in a vector of strings contains a match.

Comment: or `grep('@', strsplit(s, ' ')[[1]], value = TRUE)` where `s` is your string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also consider using the [**qdapRegex**](http://trinker.github.io/qdapRegex_dev/) package for this:

```
library(qdapRegex)
x <- 'nowy commit, nowa przygoda @oski @data2 @pankote testujemy kod @oski2'
rm_tag(x, extract=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "@oski"    "@data2"   "@pankote" "@oski2"
```

Comment: I decided to mark this as accepted, because this package fully deals with the problem of finding a tag. Also voting by the SO users was the factor in my reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: After checking, I don't think this package's regex are perfect. I got lot of false positive for example on this sentence: "Wouldn't we want to check that there is a value as well, not just the key? \`@options[:credential1].present?\`" I may continue to use this package, but with my custom regular expressions.

Comment: Should it extract `@options` or not?

Comment: It shouldn't but it extracts, its not a valid nickname on the GitHub Markdown if it's not followed by a whitechar, moreover it was surrounded by \` which stands for a code. I will modify the regex to except a space after the nick and dissalow \` around.

Comment: You can do `rm_tag(x, extract=TRUE, pattern='@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=\\s|$)')[[1]]`

Comment: That's great. Moreover I suppose I'll call earlier rm_between from the qdapRegex to remove the code chunks (text between \`). I don't need them at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`stringi`](https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi):

```
> s <- "nowy commit, nowa przygoda @oski @data2 @pankote testujemy kod @oski2"
> stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(s, "@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")
[[1]]
[1] "@oski"    "@data2"   "@pankote" "@oski2"
```

If you want matrix instead of list you can pass `simplify=TRUE`.